# Can two non-isomorphic groups have the same Cayley graphs?

Tags: group-theory, trees, combinatorial-group-theory, cayley-graphs

The question I was originally thinking about was:

Can $T_3$, the three-regular tree (the infinite tree with each vertex having valency 3) be the Cayley graph of some group with some generating set?

Since $T_2$ is $\text{Cay}(\mathbb Z, \{1\})$, and $T_4$ is $\text{Cay}(F_2=\langle a,b \rangle,\{a,b\})$, I thought for $T_3$ I could let $a,b,c$ be the three edges coming out of each vertex (in the case of $F_2$ the edges were $a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}$ but here we can't get $3 $ edges if we allow inverses of the generators to be different from themselves).

So I think $T_3=\text{Cay}(\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 , \{a,b,c\})$.

But now I could use the same logic and say $T_4=  \text{Cay}(\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 , \{a,b,c,d\}) = \text{Cay}(F_2, \{s,t\})$.

Firstly, whatever I've written so far, is it at least correct?

If it is, can two non-isomorphic groups have the same Cayley graph?

(I think they can, because I really doubt $F_2 \cong \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2$).

Comment: $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_4$ have the same Cayley graph. But they are not isomorphic (this is the unlabelled graph). See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89322/non-isomorphic-groups-with-the-same-oriented-cayley-graph).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Cool, yeah that makes sense. What I've written is correct though, right? That $T_n$ is the Cayley graph of free product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: Everything you say is correct. The logic also applies for $T_2$, and shows that the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty = C_2 * C_2$ has the same Cayley graph as $\mathbb Z$ (with respect to a natural generating set).

Comment: Another rather stupid example is that $\operatorname{Cay}(G, G)$ is a complete graph for any group $G$, even though there can be a great many groups of a given order (finite or infinite).

Comment: @SeanEberhard I disagree - $D_{\infty}=\langle a, b\mid a^2, b^2\rangle$ has Cayley graph where every vertex has degree $4$. In particular, edges are "doubled up", so if $a$ labels the directed edge $(u, v)$ then it also labels the "reverse" edge $(v, u)$. The same for $T_n$; edges are doubled for the corresponding free product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$s.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think my above criticism also works for your example? Unless you have non-standard generating sets in mind, every vertex in the Cayley graph of $C_2\times C_2$ has degree $4$ while for $C_4$ they have degree $2$?

Comment: @user1729 Yes, this is what I meant with labelling.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand. If I try and formalise the way I am viewing the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$, I am thinking of it as the set of triples $\{(g, h, a)\in (G, G, S)\mid ga=h\}$. So by "unlabelled" I assumed you meant considering the graph with edges $\{(g, h)\in (G, G)\mid \exists a\in S\text{ s.t. }ga=h\}$. Do you mean also removing "direction", i.e. removing arrows? Visually I thought this felt like cheating, but using the above formalism we'd get $\{\{g, h\}\in (G, G)\mid \exists a\in S\text{ s.t. }ga=h\}$, and then the graphs are the same. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes that by the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$ you mean the directed and labelled graph with vertex set $G$ and where we can think of the edge set as the set of ordered triples $$\{(g,h,a)\in G\times G\times S\mid ga=h\}.$$
The fact that the triples are ordered corresponds to directed edges. The third component corresponds to a label on the edge.

This definition is the one I am most familiar with, and for example is used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph).

It also assumes that by "graph" you allow multiple edges between any given two vertices (some texts call this a "multigraph"). If your definition of graph does not allow this, this your situation essentially reduces to my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4732043/10513).

By "removing labels" I mean forgetting the third component of each triple, and also the direction of each arrow, so the unlabelled Cayley graph is the [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)
$$\{\{g,h\}\in G\times G\mid \exists\:a\in S\text{ s.t. }ga=h\}.$$
Being a multiset simply means we may have multiple edges between any two given vertices.

---

There are a few questions here. So lets answer them one-by-one.

> Can two non-isomorphic groups have the same Cayley graphs?

If we remove the labels on edges, yes. The simplest family of examples is basically that pointed out by Sean Eberhard in the comments: For any group $G$, the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G,G\setminus\{1\})$ is a complete graph but where every edge is replaced by two directed edges pointing in opposite directions. As there can be a great many groups of a given order (finite or infinite), this gives non-isomorphic groups with the same unlabelled Cayley graphs.

> So I think $T_3=\text{Cay}(\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 , \{a,b,c\})$.

No. The Cayley graph *looks like* $T_3$, [if you squint a little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry), but every edge $e=(u, v)$ has a "reversed" sibling $\bar{e}=(v, u)$ with the same label. The first edge means that $u\cdot a=v$ while the second means that $v\cdot a=u$, so in particular $u\cdot a^2=u$, which is what we'd expect as $a^2=1$.

> Can $T_3$, the three-regular tree (the infinite tree with each vertex having valency 3) be the Cayley graph of some group with some generating set?

Again, no. This is because a Cayley graph must have as many incoming edges as outgoing edges; in particular every vertex of $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$ has $|S|$ outgoing edges and $|S|$ incoming edges (why?). Hence, every vertex must have even degree. As vertices of $T_3$ have odd degree, it cannot be a Cayley graph.

[Fun fact: If a group acts freely on a tree then it is free. As groups act freely on their Cayley graphs, any group with a tree as its Cayley graph must actually be free. This wasn't used above, but is nice to know anyway :-) ]

Comment: Right, I thought that making $a^2=1$ would mean that you have only $1$ edge, labelled $a=a^{-1}$. Why don't we put only $1$ edge though? As in, a directed edge from $u$ to $v$ labelled $a$. That means $a.u=v$, and $a^{-1}.v=u$, but $a^{-1}=a$, so $a.v =u$.

Comment: Oh oh I see. While constructing the Cayley graph we must construct it to not be a tree for if it were, we'd have a free action of the free product on the tree making the free product free. (It isn't free because $a$ is an element of finite order).

Comment: @Aditya Ignore the bit about freeness for now; it is interesting but too deep to be used here. It is better to do it "by hand".

Comment: "Why don't we put only 1 edge though?" - simply because every vertex must have an outgoing edge labelled $a$. So: Suppose $e=(u, v)$ is labelled $a$. Then there *must* be an edge $f=(v, x)$ labelled $a$, for $x$ some vertex. I claim that $x=u$. Now, the path $ef$ starts at $u$ and ends at $x$, and has label $a^2$. As $a^2=1$ we must have that the path $ef$ starts and ends at the same vertex, so in fact $x=u$ as claimed.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean. But it's a little confusing because we already have the edge $e$ from $u$ to $v$ labelled $a$. So the same edge is $a^{-1}$ from $v$ to $u$. Since $a^{-1}=a$, we have an outgoing edge from $v$ labelled $a$.

Comment: Moreover, the confusion I have is with convention. Here, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) it says (in the definition section) that if a generator is its own inverse then we make the edge undirected.

Comment: There are a few things here. Firstly, and most importantly, you need to be precise about the definition of a Cayley graph you are using - not all definitions are the same! I'm assuming you got the question above from a book, so you should use the definition from that book rather than wikipedia. I will add something about definitions to my answer....

Comment: Secondly, the precise quote from wikipedia is that "...it is typically represented by an undirected edge." I'd argue that "represented" is different from "is". When we draw the edge then we draw it as unlabelled, but we know underneath that it is infact two labelled edges.

Comment: The trouble is that you've made the "is $T_3$ a Cayley graph" question into nonsense, because $T_3$ is by definition an undirected graph while you are defining a Cayley graph to be directed. To me it seems fairer to identify every undirected graph with the directed graph obtained by replacing each edge with a directed edge in each direction. Then $T_3$ is the Cayley graph of $C_2*C_2*C_2$, which just feels truthy to me and we ought to set up our definitions so that it holds.

Comment: Second comment: It's clear that $G$ can be recovered from its labelled directed Cayley graph, because just looking at all the edges labelled with $s \in S$ gives you the permutation of $G$ induced by $s$, and these permutations generate the famous subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ isomorphic to $G$ (this theorem is named after somebody I think...).

Comment: In any case I heartily agree that it is important to be clear about definitions, as it makes a huge difference.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I understand your first comment. I think, on reflection, my opinions on this question are varied and best discussed in a pub :-) To your second comment, yes, certainly - this is why everything needs to be unlabelled (for some definition of unlabelled.....).

Comment: @SeanEberhard The graphs are not meant to be directed; this was an error which slipped in when I was worrying about definitions. I've corrected it now. (The point is that I allow multiple edges between any two vertices, while other people do not.)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of interesting examples of this happening! A classical infinite example is $\mathbb Z^2 = \langle a, b | ba = ab  \rangle $ and the fundamental group of the Klein bottle $\pi_1(K) = \langle a, b | ba = ab^{-1}  \rangle $.

The standard (unlabelled) Cayley graph of both of these groups is a grid, but in the Klein bottle the orientations of edges will alternate in a certain way - see below:

[image]

Of course, it is worth noting that $\mathbb Z^2$ is an index-2 subgroup of $\pi_1(K)$, so it makes sense that their structures would appear similar.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that by the Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$ you mean the *undirected* and *unlabelled* graph with vertex set $G$ and edge set $$\{\{g,h\}\in G\times G\mid \exists \: a\in S\text{ s.t. }ga=h\}.$$
This definition is used in Löh's book [Geometric Group Theory:
An Introduction](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-72254-2), although it seems uncommon.

---

> Can two non-isomorphic groups have the same Cayley graphs?

Yes. As Dietrich Burde points out in the comments, under this definition $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_4$ both have the same Cayley graph (a square).

> So I think $T_3=\text{Cay}(\mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 * \mathbb Z_2 , \{a,b,c\})$.

Yes. A rough argument is that every vertex of this Cayley graph has degree $3$, and as it is a free product the only loops in the Cayley graph correspond to products of $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ and their conjugates, but none of these actually give loops in the graph. Hence, your graph is actually a tree. (For a more formal proof, I'd look to Bass-Serre theory as this tree is the Bass-Serre tree of this group.)